# how to use if else with groovy?

Tags: groovy

i'm using Soapui and i want to add a groovy code to assert some element in a json response.

How can i use the if else statement with groovy for the following code:

```
def jsonPayload = new File("C:/temp7/file.js").text

import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def response = slurper.parseText(jsonPayload)

if (assert response.comp.type[0] == "header")
println 'header is present'
else 'header is not present'
```

when i try this i have the error org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Groovy's compiler expects the code in the if test to evaluate to something. If I run this code in the Groovy console

```
assert true
```

I don't get a Result, where if I run

```
assert true
"asdf"
```

I get

```
Result: asdf
```

so assert is a statement and it doesn't evaluate to anything. Trying to use assert as the condition of an if statement, like

```
if (assert true) {
    println('hello')
}
```

results in

```
1 compilation error:

unexpected token: assert at line: 1, column: 5
```

The if's condition needs to be an expression.

Assertions are for cases where you want it to fail loudly if what you're asserting is not true. Don't use assert unless you want it to throw an exception if the condition is not met.

Here it seems like you can do without the assert:

```
if (response.comp.type[0] == 'header')
    println('header is present')
else
    println('header is not present')
```

Comment: Thank you Nathan for the explanation, but if i try the above code, it happens nothing, even if i try 'heade' instead of 'header' There is any message.

Comment: @kirk:maybe because you left out the println on the last line?

Comment: ok it ' s resolved, i use log.info instead of println, thank you Nathan